# как распарсить такой json в qt?

Tags: c++, json, qt

здравствуйте, помогите распарсить такой json с помощью qt:

```
{
"data": [{
    "services": {
        "414": {
            "23": {
                "3": {
                    "user_id": null,
                    "state": "WAITING"
                }
            },
            "2": {
                "23": {
                    "user_id": null,
                    "state": "WAITING"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
}
```

числа генерируются рандомно... знаю что есть QJsonObject, но что-то никак не могу придумать. если б числа были фиксированные(их можно было бы использовать как ключи), то без проблем, а так не могу допереть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) есть метод [keys](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#keys), который вернет список ключей.

Если вызывать у объекта `services`, то получите список `["31"]`, по списку проходите получаете объект `"31"`, у объекта вызываете `keys` и получаете `["311", "313"]` и т.д.

---

Однако, если у вас в задаче нужно получить конкретные значения из конкретных объектов, то может попробовать [JSON Path](http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-json-path).

---

Или работать с строкой JSON и вытащить что нужно регуляркой

Comment: да, спасибо, не допер сам